# "at" command starts script but script not working

Tags: bash

I have bash scripts `meteostart` and `meteo`. Both scripts run from the command line ok.

At 09:32 the light go on but never off, like it does when `/bin/meteo` is run from command line. With cron job `/bin/meteo` also works ok (blinking 5 times on/off).

Only when script `meteo` is called from script `meteostart`, it does not work.

What could be the problem?

`meteostart`:

```
#!/bin/bash
at 09:32 today  -f /bin/meteo
```

`meteo`:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
for i in $(seq 5); do
    echo -n -e "\x37\x00\x55" | nc -u -q 1 192.168.0.6 8899 #Zone 3 on
    sleep 0.5
    echo -n -e "\x3A\x00\x55" | nc -u -q 1 192.168.0.6 8899 #Zone 3 off
done
sleep 0.5
exit
```

Comment: Btw. `seq` in a `for` loop is not very nice, better replace `$(seq 5)` with `{1..5}`.

Comment: A non-answer that has been deleted pointed out that `atd` (at daemon) must be running so that `at` works properly. OP stated in a comment below it that this is not the problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-f` [specifies](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?at) the file from which to read the job:

```
   -f file Reads the job from file rather than standard input.
```

I think what you want to do is the following:

```
echo /bin/meteo | at 09:32 today
```

Comment: Without the additional `echo` I'd say :)

Comment: @Adrian Lang   Yes, echo /bin/meteo | at 09:32 today  works now ok.

Comment: @Adrian Lang  How would  the code  for "echo /bin/meteo | at 09:32 today" be in a python script?? Thanks fro helping.

Comment: Well, that's a different question. I use [plumbum](http://plumbum.readthedocs.org/) for shell scripting in python.

Comment: @Adrian Lang Cold you please help me with plumbum? here my code        if pfd.input_pins[0].value ==0:
        if testprocess:
            testprocess.kill()
            testprocess = None
            subprocess.Popen(["/bin/aus"])
            sleep(1)
#            echo /bin/meteo | at 09:32 today

Comment: @Adrian Lange    if pfd.input_pins[0].value ==0:
        if testprocess:
            testprocess.kill()
            testprocess = None
            subprocess.Popen(["/bin/aus"])
            sleep(1)
#            echo /bin/meteo | at 09:32 today

Comment: @user3804654 Can you open a new question for this? It's pretty difficult to discuss this in the comments.

Comment: @Adrian Lang  Hi, I think I solved the porblem like this: #    if pfd.input_pins[0].value ==0:
#        cmd = "echo /bin/meteo | at 06:58 today"
#        subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to use absolute paths to everything (such as nc) in your shell script. Your environment in at may not be what you expect (PATH variable, for example).